# Handling PATCH partial updates when a key is not present

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how to get past this issue.

I have a `User` struct and it has a few fields on it. However, when decoding a JSON object for a PATCH users call, a missing key leads to the value set as *nil. The corresponding database attribute is of type `TEXT NULL`, so the result will always be stored as NULL when the key is missing.

```
type UpdateUserDTO struct {
  ID         uuid.UUID
  FirstName  string
  LastName   string
  ImageURL  *string
}
```

`ImageURL` can be nil, but when this object is sent from clients:

```
{ firstName: "Jimmy" }
```

This decodes into `ImageURL` = nil because the `imageUrl` was not present in JSON.

How can I handle partial updates without resorting to checking the presence of each field using a `map[string]struct{}` instead of my DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.20.1#Unmarshaler) to determine whether the field was omitted entirely, was provided but its value was `null`, or was provided with non-null value.

```golang
type OptString struct {
    IsValid bool
    String  *string
}

// If a field with this type has no corresponding field in the
// incoming JSON then this method will not be invoked and the
// IsValid flag's value will remain `false`.
func (s *OptString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s.String); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.IsValid = true
    return nil
}
```

```golang
type UpdateUserDTO struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    ImageURL  OptString
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/hvS5E46sgkD

---

An alternative approach, one that does not require a custom type, would be to set the Go field's value to the *current* database column's value just **before unmarshaling** the JSON. The `json.Decoder` (used by `json.Unmarshal`) will not "touch" a target's field if the incoming JSON doesn't contain a matching field.

```golang
dto := loadUpdateUserDTOFromDB(conn)
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, dto); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/grJhr4P7sgQ

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! So if I understand this, I'll have to create a type for each Opt[type]? Like `OptInt`, `OptFloat`, etc.?

Comment: I guess I could make a generic type.

Comment: @lkp Yes you can create a generic type, or a set of non generic types, whichever you prefer.

Comment: @lkp I've added an alternative solution which does not require a custom type but may require a different approach to how you implement the patch functionality.

Comment: Oh wow that's awesome. That second way seems a lot easier to implement than to do a bigger refactor! Thank you

Comment: Just an update (lol) I updated all my PATCH functionalities with this approach, and tests are checking out. You seriously saved me with a simple solution after I spent a couple days frustrated.

Comment: @lkp I'm glad you found the answer helpful.